# Regarding encoding h264 video with 1680x1050

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

What's the difference between resolution 1680x1050 and others. I use ffmpeg to encoding one video to be 1680x1050 h264, the result video is blurred, I tried qsv and x264, they has the same result.
Does it need special settings?
I use libyuv to convert argb to nv12, the code as below:

```
 uint8_t* yBuf = new uint8_t[imgSize];
                    uint8_t* uvBuf = new uint8_t[imgSize/2];
                    int ret = libyuv::ARGBToNV12((uchar*)m_newDesktopData,m_width*4,
                                                 yBuf,m_width,uvBuf,m_width,m_width,m_height);
                    if(ret != 0)
                    {
                        delete []yBuf;
                        delete []uvBuf;
                        LOG(ERROR)<<"abgrtonv12 failed:"<<ret;
                        continue;
                    }
                    memcpy(m_yuvFrame->data[0],yBuf,imgSize);
                    memcpy(m_yuvFrame->data[1],uvBuf,imgSize/2);
                    delete []yBuf;
                    delete []uvBuf;
```

I don't know where is wrong. But if I use ffmpeg to convert, the result is ok.

Comment: Nothing special about 1680x1050. Show your command and copy & paste all of the log from the command and maybe we can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: 1050 cannot be divided by 4

Comment: That doesn't matter.